# Nginx 301 redirect https for domain change

Tags: redirect, nginx, dns

I'm not familiar with Nginx. This is how I do the 301 redirect for changing domain:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name olddomain.com www.olddomain.com;
  return 301 $scheme://newdomain.com/$request_uri;
}
```

When I type in olddomain.com in my browser, I'm seeing the web pages on my newdomain but the URL is still showing olddomain.com and the browser warns for insecure connection because the ssl is not provided by the olddomain.com(they both use https). How can I redirect everything including the URL to my newdomain.com? Thanks.

Comment: The server block in your question is for `http` connections only. How do you redirect `https` connections?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I managed to make it work by adding this:

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name zacklive.com www.zacklive.com;
  return 301 $scheme://atzack.com/$request_uri;
}

Answer (score 0):

you should listen both 80 and 443 ports.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443;
    server_name  .domain.com;

    return 301 $scheme://newdomain.com$request_uri;
```

}